# 401 Unauthorized by following laracast laravel passport tutorial

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

i'am following laracast tutorial about laravel passport in [here](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13) and i following exactly the same with tutorial.

but i got this error when i click authorized button in requesting authorization

```
Client error: `POST http://laravelserver.local/oauth/token` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:
{"error":"invalid_client","message":"Client authentication failed"}
```

is it some kind of bug that appear in laravel 5.4? since the tutorial is intended for laravel 5.3

just like in the tutorial i create 2 laravel app, laravelserver.local and laravelclient.local

in laravelserver i install passport and auth, also using passport vue component.

and next i create laravelclient.local, i install passport too, and also install guzzlehttp. here is my route

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::get('/',function(){
    $query = http_build_query([
        'client_id' => 3,
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://laravelclient.local/callback',
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => '',
    ]);

    return redirect('http://laravelserver.local/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
});

Route::get('/callback', function(Request $request){
    $http = new GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $response = $http->post('http://laravelserver.local/oauth/token',[
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => 3,
            'client_secret' => 'sVyq48StpzKfivvimxcRKPzIhek0cgDhfPx4kWqo',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://laravelclient.local/callback',
            'code' => $request->code,
        ]
    ]);

    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
});
```

and in my laravelserver database (using mysql since i am running everything in XAMPP on windows 10)
oauth_clients table i have 3 record

1. **id**:1, **user_id**:null, **name**:Laravel Personal Access Client, **secret**:fnjYwNlvSMWbODmqIRHZcXFm7kvijYjs9TthHWxW, **redirect**:http://localhost, **personal_access_client**:1, **password_client**:0, **revoked**:0
2. **id**:2, **user_id**:null, **name**:Laravel Password Grant Client, **secret**:s8xLgyjq8r5KEq8XeX1030wQfKIVy5QvxPNC81OG, **redirect**:http://localhost, **personal_access_client**:0, **password_client**:1, **revoked**:0
3. **id**:3, **user_id**:1, **name**:laravelclient, **secret**:sVyq48StpzKfivvimxcRKPzIhek0cgDhfPx4kWqo, **redirect**:http://laravelclient.local/callback, **personal_access_client**:0, **password_client**:0, **revoked**:0

and in oauth_auth_codes table only have 1 record

**user_id**:1, **id**:8a07951bae2aa50a55ed615785800681d7a5dbd44beccea26638bb43bf218c8e573da5f303a56082, **client_id**:3, **scopes**:[], **revoked**:0, **expires_at**:2017-07-21 07:30:15

so it is exactly like in that tutorial and i also find this question been ask in [github](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/221) but no working answer

**update**

also i have add this in host file

```
127.0.0.1    laravelserver.local
127.0.0.1    laravelclient.local
```

and add this to httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost laravelserver.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelserver\public"
    ServerAdmin laravelserver.local
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelserver">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost laravelclient.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelclient\public"
    ServerAdmin laravelclient.local
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelclient">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you add your local domain to your host file? Because `GuzzleHttp` is actually `CURL` library, so it can't CURL to a virtual host

Comment: you mean adding this into host file?  127.0.0.1  laravelserver.local
127.0.0.1  laravelclient.local

Comment: Yes, have you done that?

Comment: yes i already add that...

Comment: Have you ran `php artisan passport:keys` yet? Do you see `oauth-private.key` and `oauth-public.key` in `storage` folder?

Comment: I got success when following this tutorial without any issues, https://mattstauffer.co/blog/introducing-laravel-passport I would suggest you should install a fresh L5.4 project and follow by Matt Stauffer tut.

Comment: yes i have oauth-private.key and oauth-public.key

Comment: well that tutorial is basicly the same as in the video

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149780/discussion-between-vietnguyen09-and-laurensius-tony).